# Potencias en for in range

Tags: python, bucle-for

recien estoy arrancando por lo que es un error simple creo. Estoy aprendiendo a usar la funcion in range y me piden que ingrese dos numeros naturales para poder potenciar el primero al segundo. Ej(4, 3)= 4*4*4

Mi problema es que solo realiza la multiplicacion una vez en vez de volver al bucle

```
numero1=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
numero2=int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
resultado=0
for i in range (0,(numero2+1)):
    resultado=numero1+numero1
```

print("El resultado es: ", resultado)

Comment: 1 no entiendo como es que 4 elevado a la 3 de 444

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varias cosas mal. En primer lugar, no estas potenciando los números, estas obteniendo el producto de los números pero en base a sumas y lo que deberías hacer es multiplicarlos para obtener la potencia.

Segundo, no es necesario sumar 1 al exponente para el `range` ya que, por más que empiece por `0` y termine en `n-1` siempre repetirá el ciclo `n` veces.

Por último y más importante `4^3` no es `444`, es `64`.

Por ende tu código debería lucir así:

```py
base = int(input("Ingrese la base: "))
exponente = int(input("Ingrese el exponente: "))

resultado = 1
for _ in range(exponente):
    resultado *=base
print("La potencia es:", resultado)
```

Utilizamos `_` en vez de `i` dado que la variable nunca se utiliza y `_` es un estándar utilizado para representar que no es necesario tomar importancia a esa variable, luego también podemos omitir el `0` en la función `range` ya que por defecto empezará desde este. Y por último y más importante declaramos la variable `resultado` con valor `1` ya que no afectará a la multiplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Todas las iteraciones del bucle hacen lo mismo. Asignan el doble de numero1 a resultado. Debería ser

```
for i in range (0,(numero2+1)):
    resultado += numero1 # Esto es lo mismo que resultado = resultado + numero1
```